# Strange dvi output from `latex`

Tags: dvi

I've just compiled a `.tex` file from the shell using the `latex` command, and it looks as if the entire text of the file has been passed through some strange substitution cipher.  Part of the `.dvi` output is below:

[image: The strange DVI output]

As you can see, the math-mode is basically fine, but the text has been garbled.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** The following code produces the figure above when compiled with `latex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}    
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Tandem mismatches effect}

    The tandem mismatches (two adjacent mismatches) are taken into account but 
the two first and positions cannot
    be mismatched. Moreover the thermodynamic parameters are still not 
available for every possible cases.
    In such a case, the program, unable to compute any relevant result, will 
quit with a warning.

For DNA duplexes, this program computes the hybridisation enthalpy and entropy from the elementary 
parameters of each Crick's pair containing the mismatch(es). 
\begin{multline*}
\Delta{}h_\mathrm{tandem-mismatch} =
\delta{}h_\mathrm{Crick's-pair-containing-tandem-mismatch} \\ + 
\sum \delta{}h_\mathrm{Crick's-pair-containing-single-mismatch}
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** Loading the `times` package causes the problem.  The document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Not hello]

Leaving out the `\usepackage{times}` line gives the output you would expect.

Comment: No problem here (using TL13). How do you preview the `dvi`?

Comment: I use Document Viewer 2.28.2 (http://www.gnome.org/projects/evince).  I'm using pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)

Comment: I see no problem with either latex or pdflatex on your sample document. What happens if you cut and paste the posted example from above back to a new document? Is it still corrupted?

Comment: Does it help simply killing Evince, it sometimes get struck by cosmic rays.

Comment: To check whether the dvi file is broken or it's the viewer's fault, try `dvitype foo.dvi | fgrep '['` and see whether the original text is intact.

Comment: Package `times` is outdated, please use instead package `math­ptmx`. (see package times on ctan)

Comment: Thanks; changing to `mathptmx` doesn't solve the problem, though.

Comment: Surprisingly, I haven't got `dvitype`.  I would have thought it would be included with the TeX distribution.

Comment: I think the problem might be that I haven't got the Times font on my computer.  Do all of you who are compiling the code with no problems have that font?

Comment: What LaTeX dist are you using, some Ubuntu mess or TUG TL?

Comment: I opened the dvi file for my second example in vim and it had the word 'hello' in it rather than any nonsense.

Comment: Why use dvi mode when using a postscript font such as Times? Is there a reason you are not using pdflatex here? I do not know how evince displays dvi, but older dvi viewers would not display scalable font formats.

Comment: My distribution says to `email bug reports to pdftex@tug.org`, so I think it's TUG TL.

Comment: I want to have separate `.pdf`, `.ps` and `.dvi` files in case people want to open the file in those formats.

Comment: So, the dvi file is correct; it's a viewing problem.

Comment: Does pdflatex generate the correct output?

Comment: Yes.  The pdf output is fine.

Comment: Yes it is a viewing problem.  Do you think it could be caused by my not having the Times font on my computer?

Comment: Hmm, just didn't try `Evince` in my earlier attempt. `My Evince` will not display the `dvi` at all. Have you tried `xdvi` instead, that works.

Comment: I think you can easily remove `.dvi` and `.ps` no-one publishes that online anymore.

Comment: `xdvi` works fine....

Comment: Think I'll leave it in that case.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem